# This poem goes downhill, quickly

Tags: riddle, rhyme

At first there were none.
It wasn't upsetting (though I sure was fretting), but not even one!

And then there were four.
I wasn't controlling while we were patrolling, but then there came more.

I really liked three!
Drunk with elation (my own destinations!) but I wasn't free.

Then, *OhMyGod,* two!!!
Screw "reprimanding," my future's expanding, boundaries eschewed.

The best of all? Four.
This isn't regressing; the *world* I'm accessing, and my feet aren't sore.

Then, an uncomfortable four.
*(Sigh)*
A constant reminder of modes that were kinder.
Freedom abduction that leads to obstruction.
A constant restraint that's not good for my taint.
Soon there'll be none once more.

Comment: Beautiful in execution *and* theme. Nicely done!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure I've grasped all the details, but I'm pretty sure what we're looking at is

> indeed a number of wheels, as Beastly Gerbil thinks, but *over the life of an individual* rather than over history. (A little like the famous Sphinx's riddle.)

At first there were none.
It wasn't upsetting (though I sure was fretting), but not even one!

> To begin with, we have a baby. Might be lying or crawling or sitting, but no wheels involved.

And then there were four.
I wasn't controlling while we were patrolling, but then there came more.

> In a pram. Or maybe a toy car (not steerable, hence "wasn't controlling").

I really liked three!
Drunk with elation (my own destinations!) but I wasn't free.

> On a tricycle.

Then, OhMyGod, two!!!
Screw "reprimanding," my future's expanding, boundaries eschewed.

> On a bike. A big step in the life of a child.

The best of all? Four.
This isn't regressing; the world I'm accessing, and my feet aren't sore.

> Grown up enough to drive a car. You can abruptly get to all sorts of places that weren't practicable before.

Then, an uncomfortable four.
(Sigh)
A constant reminder of modes that were kinder.
Freedom abduction that leads to obstruction.
A constant restraint that's not good for my taint.
Soon there'll be none once more.

> An old person in a wheelchair, perhaps -- in the last line, looking forward mournfully to the grave.

It's possible, but I think worse, to

> treat some of these as counts of hands/feet (hence, more Sphinx-like) rather than wheels. Immobile infant, crawling baby, etc. The fours still need to be wheels, and I find the three especially unconvincing.

Comment: I got sniped - 1 minute

Comment: Pretty sure on my wheels guess but I like this much more as an answer, and I’m guessing this is correct - and the title makes sense as well I guess...

Comment: Yes, nicely done, though hands/feet is going to give me nightmares :-0 Your ☑  is in the mail.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by [Baeastly Gerbil's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/65429/46886) answer.  I think this is about

> The number of wheels used by a person through their lifetime

At first there were none.
It wasn't upsetting (though I sure was fretting), but not even one!

> newborn babies do not go anywhere.

And then there were four.
I wasn't controlling while we were patrolling, but then there came more.

> being pushed around the neighborhood in a (four-wheeled) stroller

I really liked three!
Drunk with elation (my own destinations!) but I wasn't free.

> a toddler gets a tricycle

Then, OhMyGod, two!!!
Screw "reprimanding," my future's expanding, boundaries eschewed.

> first bicycle :D

The best of all? Four.
This isn't regressing; the world I'm accessing, and my feet aren't sore.

> getting a car as a teenager/young adult

Then, an uncomfortable four.
(Sigh)
A constant reminder of modes that were kinder.
Freedom abduction that leads to obstruction.
A constant restraint that's not good for my taint.
Soon there'll be none once more.

> getting old and feeble and confined to a (four-wheeled) wheelchair

Title

> like Beastly Gerbil pointed out - those go downhill fast -- too fast, if not properly controlled.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that this poem refers to

> The number of wheels on automobiles

Title: This poem goes downhill quickly

> Things with wheels sure would go downhill quickly

---

At first there were none.
It wasn't upsetting (though I sure was fretting), but not even one!

> To start, no automobile had been invented

And then there were four.
I wasn't controlling while we were patrolling, but then there came more.

> The first wagon was invented - but it was horse led. Then came cars with 4 wheels.

I really liked three!
Drunk with elation (my own destinations!) but I wasn't free.

> 3 wheeled cars were then invented by Karl Benz

Then, OhMyGod, two!!!
Screw "reprimanding," my future's expanding, boundaries eschewed.

> The motorcycle (motorbike) was invented with just two wheels.

The best of all? Four.
This isn't regressing; the world I'm accessing, and my feet aren't sore.

> Despite going back to the trusty old 4 wheels, the newest sports cars were invented and cars now certainly allow you to travel quickly without walking

Then, an uncomfortable four.
(Sigh)

> Most likely a bus - which can be very uncomfortable

A constant reminder of modes that were kinder.
Freedom abduction that leads to obstruction.

> Buses certainly make *me* at least wish I was in a car...

A constant restraint that's not good for my taint.
Soon there'll be none once more.

> We now have aircraft, which don't need wheels and the invention of flying cars may be very soon.

---

Could be way off, but hopefully this is quite close...

Comment: Hmm. I'm not convinced, especially by the last verse - buses go back to the 1830s, predating any kind of cars.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The last verse I struggled with the most - all the others can be argued (there is a lot of debate about when different automobiles where actually invented and by who) - but a bus was the only ‘uncomfortable’ four wheeled automobile I could think of